# How can I debug NSObject observers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb

Let's say I've got a Player instance, and I want to add an observer to their score so I can update the score display in my iOS application. I believe I should be calling a method that looks like this to add the observer:

```
[[self.game player] addObserver:self
                     forKeyPath:@"score" 
                        options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                        context:nil];
```

In the same class, I then have a method defined that should receive this message:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

However, the breakpoint that I have placed in this method never gets hit.

I would like to know how to diagnose this issue. I have verified that player instance is filled, and when the score is updated, the same instance is updated.

If it helps, I have just converted my project to ARC, but this code above is new and has never worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your key path "score" is not KVO compliant (are you not defining a @property for *score?) or the adding of the observer method is never being called. You can easily diagnose the latter by placing a breakpoint onto the line of code in your first snippet, and verifying that an observer indeed is being registered.

Comment: I called [[self.game player] valueForKey:@"score"] which consequently returned nil so I'm guessing that something else is wrong with my application. Thanks for your time which I suspect I have just wasted.

Comment: OK, it turns out that viewDidLoad executes before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, so I was relying on something that wasn't available at the time. Here, have some reputation anyway.